# unhashable type: 'list' when creating a combination function with Python

Tags: python, list, types, tuples, combinations

I'm currently trying to create a combination function that has the equal function to the `itertools.combinations`.

The following code is the code that I am working on:

```
def my_combs(s, num):
    if num == 0:
        return [[]]
    res = []
    for i in range(0, len(s)):
        m = s[i]
        rems = s[i + 1:]
        for p in my_combs(rems, num-1):
            res.append([m]+p)
    return res

from itertools import combinations
test = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(set(combinations(test, 2)))
print(set(my_combs(test, 2)))
```

The result I want to get is

```
{(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (3, 4), (2, 4)}
```

But I keep getting an error that says `unhashable type: 'list'`

And then, when I change the `print(set(my_combs(test, 2)))` to `print(my_combs(test, 2))`, I get

```
[[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 4]]
```

While the elements of the results seem to be the same,

**I want to get the results in tuples (i.e { ( ) } ), instead of lists (i.e [ [ ] ]).**

Is there any way for me to solve the error and get the results I want with the condition of unchanging any of the print statements?

 (i.e I want to have the print statement as `print(set(my_combs(test, 2)))` and change only the `my_combs()` function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want tuples instead of lists - just use tuples instead of lists :)

```
def my_combinations(s, num):
    if num == 0:
        return [()]                              # HERE
    res = []
    for i in range(0, len(s)):
        m = s[i]
        rems = s[i + 1:]
        for p in my_combinations(rems, num-1):
            res.append((m,)+p)                   # HERE
    return res

from itertools import combinations
test = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(set(combinations(test, 2)))
print(set(my_combinations(test, 2)))
```

Note that one-element tuple has to have a comma in it: `(m,)`; without it, `(m)`, it is just something in parentheses.

Comment: Wow Thank you very much for your answer. I was having the problem because of (m,)...
I guess this was why I kept getting an error even if I changed the third line ``` return [()]```.

Answer (score 0):

Item in set should be hashable. List is mutable, Tuple is hashable, So change list to tuple.

Change last line to :

```
print(set(tuple(item) for item in my_combinations(test, 2)))
```

Comment: I would actually like to change ```my_combs()``` rather than the print. I should have made my question more specific. My apologies...
I edited the question to be more specific.